# How to send JSON Object from React Native to Laravel Server?

Tags: json, laravel, react-native, post, axios

I have these JSON Objects that I want to send to my API so I can save them on my database :

#### JSON Objects

```
const utility = {
    con: [
        { "name": "Michel", "phone": "+213 93 783 28 73", "users_id": "1"},
        { "name": "Annie", "phone": "+213 93 783 28 72", "users_id": "1"},
        { "name": "Rory", "phone": "+16505551212", "users_id": "1"},
        { "name": "CESI", "phone": "+213 58 357 31 78", "users_id": "1"}
    ],
  }
```

#### Post request from React Native :

```
export default function Contact({ navigation }) {
    const { user, logout } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [contact, setContact] = useState([]);
    const [count, setCount] = useState('');
  
    //console.log(utility.con)
    const uticontact = utility.con;

    console.log(uticontact)

    const SubmitCon = async () => {
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user.token}`;
      try {
        axios.post(`/api/contact`, {
          data : JSON.stringify(utility.con)
        });
        console.log(`Contacts successfully added`);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
```

When I submit with the function I have a 500 error code

#### Laravel controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->json()->all() as $record) {
            $contact = new Contact();
            $contact->name = $record['name'];
            $contact->phone = $record['phone'];
            $contact->users_id = $record['users_id'];
            $contact->save();
        }
        
        return response()->json([
            "code" => 200,
            "message" => "Contacts added successfully"
        ]);
    }
```

When I try send this with Insomnia it's working, so how should I do ?

```
[
    { "name": "Michel", "phone": "+213 93 783 28 73", "users_id": "1"},
    { "name": "Annie", "phone": "+213 93 783 28 72", "users_id": "1"},
    { "name": "Rory", "phone": "+16505551212", "users_id": "1"},
    { "name": "CESI", "phone": "+213 93 783 28 73", "users_id": "1"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a service via Fetch API in React-Native in same or in different in a different file
i.e. service.js

```
const api_url  = "www.myUrl.com/"
export function submitContact(data) {
    return fetch(api_url+'/api/contact', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });

}
```

then import and it call it inside your component

```
import { SubmitContact} from './service'

export default function Contact({ navigation }) {
    const { user, logout } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [contact, setContact] = useState([]);
    const [count, setCount] = useState('');
  
    //console.log(utility.con)
    const uticontact = utility.con;

    console.log(uticontact)
      //Send Post Request 
      submitContact(utility.con).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
         // perform  some action  on  your  response

        }) ;
   
    };
```